# Accept only types from model in POST JSON

Tags: asp.net, json.net

I have problem with deserializing JSON. Asp.Net Core (JSON.NET)  deserialize integer to string. I want only accept field with string, I do not want to convert integer to string. Here is my model to which JSON is deserialize:

```
    public class TeamPost
{

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

}
```

And when I send this JSON to app:

```
{
"name": 123,
 "phone": "+48501441199"
}
```

It is converting integer to string. I want to throw an error because I expected string but I get integer.

Should I use JsonConverter ? Is there any global option for this. I could not find anything

Comment: Not clear what do you want to do. Please elaborate few more.

Comment: Have you tried using [Datatype=Datatype.String] attribute on Name property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: The problem is that when "name" is numeric it is converted to string. I want to throw an error that "name" is numeric not string(text). Program should accept only string in "name" in JSON. @UP There is not anything like DataType.String, I found only DataType.Text